# DATEDIFF check for one minute is actually between one and two minutes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using DATEDIFF to make sure a certain action cannot happen more than once a minute.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM FOOD_ACTION
WHERE 
DATEDIFF(MINUTE,INSERT_DT,GETDATE()) <= 1
```

`INSERT_DT` is a date column with the same format that `GETDATE()` returns

If anything is returned from this query, the action is not allowed to happen.

The thing is, it only *kind of* works. I've had it range from a minute and 10 seconds all the way up to almost two minutes before it will let the action happen again. There doesn't seem to be any consistency in if its closer to one minute or two, and I've confirmed that `GETDATE()` returns the same exact time as my application does when it sets the `INSERT_DT` column.

What's up with the inconsistent and incorrect timing?

Comment: Take difference in seconds and use `< 60`. The short explanation is that the seconds portion of the time is ignored by `datediff()`.

Comment: the reason is that 01:00:01 is 119 seconds away from 01:02:00 where the value will finally become 2

Comment: remembered a principle I decided on once - it's often better to add the time to the start time and wait until the time has passed that future time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do a datediff, T-SQL will look for when the time/date part boundaries have crossed to increment the difference.

So with:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2000-01-01T12:51:59.999',
        @EndDate DATETIME = '2000-01-01T12:52:00:000'

SELECT DATEDIFF(minute, @StartDate, @EndDate)
```

you will get a result of: 1
even though there was only 1ms difference between the dates.

In practice I solve this issue by going to a lower granularity and look for the cross over myself, ie:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2000-01-01T12:51:59.999',
        @EndDate DATETIME = '2000-01-01T12:52:00:000'

SELECT 
   CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(second, @StartDate, @EndDate) >= 59 THEN CAST(1 as bit)
        ELSE CAST(0 as bit)
   END as InNewMinute
```

That'll give 0 as obviously 1ms is not 1 minutes difference.

*Note: the code above is obviously only for handling 1 minute difference*

See: [MSDN DATEDIFF (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189794.aspx) (look at datePart Boundaries)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM FOOD_ACTION
  WHERE 
   DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,INSERT_DT,GETDATE()) <= 60000
```

---

also why access all data to indicate nothing should happen?  Better to do

```
SELECT 1 as marker 
  WHERE 
   DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND,INSERT_DT,GETDATE()) <= 60000
```

then if 1 is returned, use that as an indication, that way read no data and cut network traffic possibly